# Should read/unread status in a mobile messaging app be handled client or server side?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, message

I'm working on an iPhone messaging app and trying to implement read/unread status for messages. I guess there are two ways of doing this:

1. Handle it server-side: add a 'read' column on Messages table and update it to true everytime a user views a message.
2. Handle it client-side: Use Coredata to store and update 'read' status and display accordingly.

I am wondering what approaches most messaging apps take and what are pros and cons of each. Thanks!

Comment: I Handled it from server side. In future, if you want to make structure like replies under the same parent message. Server side would give you more flexibility and device independence